# Using pushstate to load certain pages on my ajax website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pushstate

I am installing a social network sharing plugin to my website and I notice that I can only share one link.... the main index link.. How would I go about using pushstate to change the url in my browser to load each specific page on my website when sharing. Becuase using my ajax code I only have one URL and thats https://trillumonopoly.com. Im not familiar with pushstate but ive read that it is what im looking for.

for example if I want to social share the page for music on my website so when people click the link it will take them to my website index page with that specific page loaded into the div. How will I do it.

heres my jquery / ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadMainContent('main');

    $('body').delegate('.navMenu', 'click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        loadMainContent($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});

function loadMainContent(page) {
    $('#main').load('pages/' + page + '.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a url like `yoursite/someroute` then you'll get a `not found` error. So you'll need to tell apache to serve index.php for those routes using [rewrite](https://gist.github.com/santthosh/7dabf08fa3859361ef1e).

In document.ready you need to check for the url (`document.location.pathname`) and load the content according to what the path is.

The index page should always show a loading spinner that will be replaced with the actual content based on the path name in the url

Here is some simple sample code of how you could do this:

```
//if path is /contact then return object with the url to php content page
//  and title of the page
const pathToPage = path => {
  switch (path) {
    case "/contact":
      return {
        url:"/contact.php"
        ,title:"Contact"
        ,path:path
      };
  }
}
//when user navigates back and forward
window.addEventListener(
  "popstate"
  ,event =>
    //only set content, do not mess with history
    onlyLoadmain(
      pathToPage(location.pathname)
    )
);
//load main content with or without messing with history
const loadMainBuilder = (push)=>(page)=> {
  //if page is undefined then path is not of known content
  if(page!==undefined){
    if(push){
      //set the url
      history.pushState(
        {},
        page.title
        ,page.path
      );
    }
    document.title = page.title
    //@todo: should show loading here
    //$('#main').html(loading);
    $('#main').load(
      'pages/' + page.url + '.php'
    );
  }
}
const loadMainAndPush = loadMainBuilder(true);
const onlyLoadmain = loadMainBuilder(false);
//... other code
$(document).ready(function () {
  //load the content of current page
  //  when user gets a url in their email like yoursite/contact the
  //  apache rewrite rule will serve index.php but main content is
  //  showing loading untill your code actually replaces it with something
  onlyLoadmain(pathToPage(location.pathname));

  $('body').delegate('.navMenu', 'click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //the element clicked should have href with the path, not the php file path
      //so /contacts not /pages/contacts.php
      loadMainAndPush(pathToPage($(this).attr('href')));
  });
});
```

Comment: the paths to all the pages loading inside of the div are inside a directory called pages. in my ajax code it specifies that the path and the file's type.... changing it to "href" will mean I will have to specify the file and extension? Also when specifiying the loading image do i make it a page or just just load up the image itself.

Comment: @DigiGodHymself Just have the loading image be part of the main php page, when content is received the JavaScript will replace it with the content. The href should be what you see in the url and is used by `pathToPage` to figure out what the title should be and what php page to load, for example: `http://example.com/contact` the value for href is `/contact`